# Problem with Lualatex and hyperref

Tags: hyperref, luatex, matlab2tikz

I have a lot of matlab2tikz generated figures which look good, but when I input them in my maincode it leady to exceeded capacity error. I figured out, when I place each Plot on a new page the memory is not exceeded. Why is that?

And now the important question: I used Lualatex as workaround by saving the mythesis.tex file and run "lualatex with lualatex -shell-escape mythesis.tex" in a command window. I receive a error message that contains this info:

```
Package hyperref Warning: 
Wrong driver `hpdftex.def'
(hyperref)                pdfTeX is running in PDF mode.
(hyperref)                Forcing driver `hluatex.def'.
```

And when I check my created PDF, I do not see any citications.

I use Miktex and Texmaker.

this is what I use in the main file regarding tikz:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows.meta}
\tikzstyle{bag} = [align=center]
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
```

And this is all to hyperref:

```
\usepackage[pdftex, raiselinks, pdfpagelabels, plainpages=true, hypertexnames=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}, linktoc=all]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    pdfauthor = {Max Mustermann},
    pdftitle = {Thema der Arbeit},
    pdfsubject = {Studienarbeit},
    %pdfkeywords = {},
    %pdfcreator = {LaTeX with hyperref package}
}
```

Comment: When you load the `hyperref` package, you're specifying `pdftex` as an option. Changing that to `luatex` may resolve the issue with references, it's hard to say without a complete minimal working example.

Comment: If you remove the `pdftex` option from `\usepackage[pdftex, ...]{hyperref}`, the package should detect that you're running LuaTeX.